# Bootstrap grid not working in IE 7 and 8

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 grid aimed at working on desktop, mobile and tablet devices. Everything works fine on recent versions of Firefox and IE 9+, but it fails on anything less than IE 9. By fail I mean that the grid system displays the mobile version even on desktops.

Scripts:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My grid is as follows; I have removed a lot of the text from the divs for easy reading:

```
    <!--- BEGIN Mobile Navbar -->
  <header class="navbar navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav visible-xs" style="margin: -20px 0 15px 0;">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="nav-mobile-outer" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a href="../" class="navbar-brand" id="nav-mobile-header">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" id="nav-mobile-inner" role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#" id="nav-mobile-link"><img src="images/arrow.gif" class="mobile-arrow">Orkney Demand & Generation</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--- END Mobile Navbar -->

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" id="header-left"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 visible-md visible-lg" id="sse-logo"></div>

    <!--- Begin Desktop & Tablet Navbar -->
    <nav class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 hidden-xs" id="nav-desktop-container">
    </nav>
    <!--- End Desktop & Tablet Navbar -->

    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:30px;"><!--- Spacer --></div>

    <!--- Begin Desktop & Tablet Mid Section -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" id="left-widget">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" id="right-widget" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
    <!--- End Desktop & Tablet Mid Section -->

    <div class="col-xs-12"><!--- Spacer --><br /></div>

  </div>
```

I have tried adding the following code to no avail:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bootstrap/respond/src/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/html5shiv/src/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Are you using respond.js? See the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs

Comment: I am not using respond.js, no.

Answer (score 4):

According the documentation:

> Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are also supported, however, please be aware that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported by these browsers. In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of Respond.js to enable media query support.

Try adding respond.js and html5shiv to your into your head tag using IE conditionals:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>';
 <script src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>';
<![endif]-->
```

And change the meta tag to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried adding respond.js and html5shiv but neither have worked. The meta tag is already set to that.

Comment: IE8 *requires* respond.js for media queries to work with Bootstrap 3, otherwise it will show the mobile layout. That's all there is to it. Do either of those scripts leave any errors in the developer console? Are you absolutely sure the path to the scripts is correct?

Comment: I am 100% sure I am using the correct path. I have also tried including it without the IE conditional. <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have also tried using respond.js as a local file rather than linking to it on an external server.

Comment: I am also getting no errors thrown by in the developer console; it just appears appears in mobile view regardless of width.

Comment: Hi John, I am facing the same problem . Have you managed to resolve the problem ? If yes please share.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)? Using this method you can make Ie8-IE7 to look like just desktop version as it should be. I usually recommend this since IE7-8 lack css3 support even with respond.js:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>  <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>  <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The default bootstrap container is like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
width: 1170px;
}
```

With Modernizr you can add it on the top like this:

```
.ie-lt9 .container {width: 1170px;}
```

Comment: I tried adding the code you suggested to no effect.

Comment: you added Modernizr plugin? You added New head element like the ones on my answer? you have meta for this: like - `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`